# How can I have Monaco's onDidChangeModelContent() function fire on every keystroke?

Tags: monaco-editor

I'm trying to capture the value of a Monaco editor's content on every keystroke. I've tried using the editor's `onDidChangeModelContent()` function, but this appears to fire inconsistently, when trying it out in the [playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html) with this code:

```
const editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
    value: "function hello() {\n\talert('Hello world!');\n}",
    language: "javascript"
});

editor.onDidChangeModelContent = e => {
    console.log(editor.getValue());
};
```

I only see console entries when I auto-complete an Intellisense suggestion with tab, not on every keystroke. Is there another event listener I should be using, or some other technique I should try?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured it out; the example code was using `onDidChangeModelContent()` incorrectly. To set an event listener, the client code needs to *call* `onDidChangeModelContent()`, not set it. This code works:

```
editor.onDidChangeModelContent(e => {
    console.log(editor.getValue());
});
```